# About how to speed up in assignment

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, assignment

I would like to know if there is a way for increasing the speed of the following computation:
I have a list, let's call it `list`, and another list of  values, val. I wish to create a sparse matrix in the following way: The only nonzeros elements of the matrix are the positions of list (2 components) where the value is val[[i]]. I have generate this code:
`Mathematica`

list = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6,
4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}};

val = Table[i^2, {i, Length[list]}];

matrix = Table[0., {i, 13}, {j, 13}];(* 13 is just an example *)

For[i=1,i<= Length[list], i++, matrix[[list[[i]][[1]], list[[i]][[2]] ]] = val[[i]]];

Do you know a way for improving the speed? I ask this because if the length of list is long the loop requires much time to do.

Answer (score 5):

```
sa = SparseArray[list -> val]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ sa
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 16 \\
>  0 & 25 & 36 & 49 & 64 & 81 \\
>  0 & 0 & 100 & 121 & 144 & 169 \\
>  0 & 0 & 196 & 0 & 225 & 256 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Use the second argument to specify the desired dimensions: For example, to get a sparse matrix with 10 rows and 9 columns, use

```
sa2 = SparseArray[list -> val, {10, 9}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ sa2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 25 & 36 & 49 & 64 & 81 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 100 & 121 & 144 & 169 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 196 & 0 & 225 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Wow! Many thanks, kglr. One more question: What about if val is a matrix instead a list, call it M, and I want to assign matrix[[list[[i]][[1]], list[[i]][[2]] ]] = M[[list[[i]][[1]], list[[i]][[2]] ]] ?

Comment: @Benigno, use `SparseArray[list -> Extract[M, list]]`?

Comment: I think we can close this question with the two great answers of kglr.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = SparseArray[MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]]^2 &, list], {13, 13}];

m // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 25 & 36 & 49 & 64 & 81 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 100 & 121 & 144 & 169 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 196 & 0 & 225 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$